# Can I ask about preference of a programming practice that doesn't practically affect the code?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

The question is a little vague, so let me elaborate: I want to ask whether or not the uers of Stack Overflow include `return 0` in their code even though ISO C++ doesn't require it. This doesn't really affect the code except to close out main() more clearly, but I am curious about it. Is this kind of question okay to ask on Stack Overflow?

Comment: no, you cannot ask whether programmers prefer Cheetos or Doritos when they code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, it tends to depend on how you phrase it.

- **Do you return 0 from main()?** - will almost certainly be closed.
- **Is it better to return 0 from main()?** - very likely to be closed.
- **Should I always return 0 from main()?** - fairly likely to be closed.
- **When should I return 0 from main()?** - might stay open.
- **What are the reasons for/against returning 0 from main()?** - probably will stay open.

In essence, if you're able to phrase the question in such a way that you are asking for *facts* as opposed to *opinions*, the likelihood of staying open goes up (but it still might get closed, especially if it's a dupe as gnovice has pointed out).

Disclaimer: Standards tend to vary somewhat among sub-communities on Stack Overflow, and I'm not sure how the C/C++ folks would react to these; I am pretty confident in the accuracy of these statements for the .NET/SQL groups.

Comment: This is good information. I don't really think that other question is asking the same thing, so it wouldn't really be a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, because you are asking a user's opinion.

It will be closed as **subjective and argumentative**:
It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument.

Comment: yea, in theory it's correct, but in practice we have a ton of these kind of questions. Just look at the entire `best-practices` tag.

Comment: Just because we have a ton of these questions does not make it ok

Comment: Well does that mean I can't ask any questions that could result in differing opinions? I mean, there's only two choices with return 0, and it seems like a valid best-practices question looking at the other ones on there.

Comment: try it @mau, report here the result...

Answer (score 1):

It's the big huge gray area. Label it as `best-practices` and make it CW and it may survive though

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you should ask your question is probably a moot point, since it is already pretty much addressed by this [other existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239/why-does-int-main-compile). To summarize the answers there, there will be an implicit `return 0` if you don't explicitly add it, so the inclusion or exclusion of a return statement is a subjective individual preference that doesn't appear to matter (and therefore requires no real discussion, in my opinion).

So, not only could your question get closed for being a bit too subjective, it could also be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Eh, but that doesn't really answer my question. I understand that it's inserted by default if you don't include it, but I want to know if people /do/ include it. I've seen differing opinions on different places on the web, which I why I'm curious to see the general consensus.

Comment: @Maulrus: I think it does answer your question, because it points out that there is no real objective difference between the two different cases, and it is thus a purely subjective matter (discussions of which aren't generally welcomed on SO).

Comment: I agree